# Reduce memory usage by json.loads with multiprocessing or Dask in Python

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, out-of-memory, dask

I have a csv file with 1 million rows and 3gb data size. I used panda `read_csv` to convert it to DataFrame and it works well.

Next now i have to format the data columns and append another column also according to the value of some columns. To do this, i am using Dask DataFrame npartitions then apply row-wise. We have 7.5gb of RAM at our instance, but it hangs and kill the process with MemoryError.

This is my code to format the data columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import dask.dataframe as dd
import multiprocessing

def formatting_data(data):

    print("cleaning and formatting data")

    data["IsBadJson"] = False

    data["BadJsonStr"] = None

    data = dd.from_pandas(data, npartitions=4*multiprocessing.cpu_count())
             .map_partitions(lambda df: df.apply(lambda row: parse_data_to_json(row), axis=1))
             .compute(scheduler='processes')

    return data
```

Below is code for function `parse_data_to_json` we are using for formatting

```
def parse_data_to_json(x):

    try:

        if x.get("RequestSent") == "nan":

            x["RequestSent"] = None
            x["IsBadJson"] = True
            x["BadJsonStr"] = str(x.get("RequestSent"))

        else:

            x["RequestSent"] = json.loads(x.get("RequestSent"))
            x["IsBadJson"] = False
            x["BadJsonStr"] = None

    except Exception as error:
        print("Found an error value in Tax Json field RequestSent: {}, error details: {}".format(x.get("RequestSent"), error))

        print("{}-{}-{}".format(None, True, str(x.get("RequestSent"))))

        x["RequestSent"] = None
        x["IsBadJson"] = True
        x["BadJsonStr"] = str(x.get("RequestSent"))


    try:

        if x.get("ResponseReceived") == "nan":

            x["ResponseReceived"] = None
            x["IsBadJson"] = True
            x["BadJsonStr"] = str(x.get("ResponseReceived"))

        else:

            x["ResponseReceived"] = json.loads(x.get("ResponseReceived"))
            x["IsBadJson"] = False
            x["BadJsonStr"] = None

    except Exception as error:
        print("Found an error value in Tax Json field RequestSent: {}, error details: {}".format(x.get("ResponseReceived"), error))

        print("{}-{}-{}".format(None, True, str(x.get("ResponseReceived"))))

        x["ResponseReceived"] = None
        x["IsBadJson"] = True
        x["BadJsonStr"] = str(x.get("ResponseReceived"))

    return x
```

Comment: Wait. So what's your strategy to reduce memory usage? Have you considered [`blaze`](https://github.com/blaze/blaze)?

Comment: we are trying to use Dask. so that we can apply the formatting to columns in processes for some of rows and after one process ends, memory used by json.loads should be released.

Comment: As per i studied, Memory mostly used by `json.loads(x.get("RequestSent"))` inside parse_data_to_json method

Comment: You are getting close votes because your parsing function is over-long and complicated, and you don't get to showing what you want to do with this data.- presumably not just load it into memory (where it doesn't fit). Also, you should include a sample of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend allowing Dask to load your data directly from CSV, rather than pass it a Pandas dataframe.  See https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/best-practices.html#load-data-with-dask